# How to make UIImage round

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, mapkit, mkannotation

I am trying to make the annotation.image round. But I don't know how. How would i go about making a UIImage round.

```
 //Customize Annotation
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    let annotationIdentifier = "Identifier"

    var annotationView: MKAnnotationView! = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)

    if annotationView != nil {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation
    } else {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)


        annotationView.image = profileImage.image

        annotationView.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25)

        annotationView.autoresizesSubviews = true
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.detailDisclosure) as UIView
    }


      return annotationView
}
```

}

[Currently looks like this on a map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMIIB.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should play around with the `cornerRadius` property. 
It will be something like:

```
annotationView.layer.cornerRadius = yourCornerRadius
```

If you set the `yourCornerRadius` as half of height or width of the `annotationView` you should get a round `annotationView`.

If that doesn't works add this line too

```
annotationView.layer.maskToBounds = true
```

Comment: Tried it. But I got this error when I set maskToBound to true --> clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x618000421fc0>> cannot show callout with clipsToBounds enabled'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 0):

How about adding imageView?

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25))
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image.png");
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.layer.bounds.size.width / 2
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
annotationView.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: What would I put for the UIImage(named: ) ...? I

Comment: @JoseMelendez It can be `profileImage.image` here

Comment: I am not getting any errors but it still not working. Image is still squared.

Comment: Your solution helped me the most. What I was doing wrong was that I had the annotationView.image set to profile.image. All I had to do was delete that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
func getRoundedImage(originalImage: UIImage,view: UIView,radius:CGFloat,borderWidth:CGFloat) -> UIImage?{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, false, 0)
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view.bounds.insetBy(dx: borderWidth / 2, dy: borderWidth / 2), cornerRadius: radius)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context!.saveGState()
        path.addClip()
        originalImage.draw(in: view.bounds)
        UIColor.gray.setStroke()
        path.lineWidth = borderWidth
        path.stroke()
        let roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return roundedImage

    }
```

Comment: What do i put for the view paramater?

Comment: Can you try this line? --  annotationView.image = getRoundedImage(originalImage: profileImage.image, view: annotationView, radius: self.annotationView.frame.width/2, borderWidth: 1.0) -- in place of   annotationView.image = profileImage.image

Comment: it finds nil when it unwraps this  context!.saveGState() in the function.

Answer (score 0):

To make a square a circle, just set its corner radius to half its width/height.

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 12.5 //Half the sideLength of the imageView
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```